# How do I get many decimal places out of php microtime(true)?

Tags: php, microtime

In part of my code when I print `microtime(true)` it gives me a number like this `1410876482.803832` (6 decimal places), but other times it gives me a number like this `1410876484.86` (2 decimal places).

How do I get it to consistently give my 6 decimal places?

Comment: `sprintf('%.6f', microtime(true))`

Answer (score 1):

look for the setting **[precision]** - this controls the number of decimal places used.

Also see:

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php
  http://uk.php.net/microtime

Hope this helps